# advantages or disadvantages of pulsed laser vs continuous-wave (CW) laser

Tags: visible-light, laser, radio-frequency, laser-cavity

What are the advantages and disadvantages of pulsed vs CW laser? Does pulsed laser have more power compared to CW laser, or it is vice versa?
If I have to guess, for long distance communication, pulsed laser is preferred. Is this true? And if it is true, then why is this the case?